# Saving Variables Across Calls in WCF as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, session, windows-services

I created a WCF Service Library, which I host via a Windows Service.

Is it possible to save information across API calls?

I know that if I host the WCF Service Library in IIS with ASP.Net compatibility turned on and making a few modifications to the WCF library that I can use 
`HttpContext`.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = <value>;
```

WCF started as a Windows Service does not have ASP.Net support to the best of my knowledge, as the library is not hosted by IIS. Is there a way for a WCF library launched via a Windows Service to save information across calls for a specific caller?

Comment: WCF supports instantiation PerCall, PerSession (default, one instance per caller) and Singleton. Take a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickrain/2009/06/15/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-1/

Comment: ....adding to @Evertude, you most likely want `PerSession`.  You don't want `PerCall`